# MXMLC Ant task results in java.lang.OutOFMemoryError

Tags: java, apache-flex, ant, mxmlc

I'm making a change to a set of code for a Flex project that I didn't write and was set up to compile using ant tasks. I assume that the codebase was stable at the last checkin but I'm running into memory issues when trying to build a project using MXMLC and ant (see stack trace below). Before, I was just getting an out of memory error. I tried using a different machine and got this more verbose exception (including problems with the image fetcher). I've tried using various versions of the SDK, I've tried replacing the `<mxmlc>` tag with `<exec executable="mxmlc">` with no luck. Here is my java version in case that has anything to do with it:

```
» java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01-279, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Buildfile: build.xml

compileSWF:
     [echo] Compiling main.swf... 
    [mxmlc] Loading configuration file /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in/sdks/4.0.0beta2/frameworks/flex-config.xml
    [mxmlc] Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [mxmlc]     at java.awt.image.PixelGrabber.setDimensions(PixelGrabber.java:360)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder.setDimensions(ImageDecoder.java:62)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.sendHeaderInfo(JPEGImageDecoder.java:71)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:119)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:246)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
    [mxmlc] /src/com/amtrak/components/map/MapAsset.mxml: Error: exception during transcoding: Failed to grab pixels for image /src/assets/embed_assets/images/zoomed_map_wide.jpg
    [mxmlc] 
    [mxmlc] /src/com/amtrak/components/map/MapAsset.mxml: Error: Unable to transcode /assets/embed_assets/images/zoomed_map_wide.jpg.
    [mxmlc] 
    [mxmlc] Error: Java heap space
    [mxmlc] 
    [mxmlc] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [mxmlc]     at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:112)
    [mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.util.ObjectList.<init>(ObjectList.java:30)
    [mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.ArgumentListNode.<init>(ArgumentListNode.java:30)
    [mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.NodeFactory.argumentList(NodeFactory.java:116)
    [mxmlc]     at macromedia.asc.parser.NodeFactory.argumentList(NodeFactory.java:97)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationGenerator.generateBinding(ImplementationGenerator.java:563)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationGenerator.generateBindingsSetupFunction(ImplementationGenerator.java:864)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationGenerator.generateBindingsSetup(ImplementationGenerator.java:813)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationGenerator.generateInitializerSupportDefs(ImplementationGenerator.java:1813)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationGenerator.generateClassDefinition(ImplementationGenerator.java:1005)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationGenerator.<init>(ImplementationGenerator.java:201)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationCompiler.generateImplementationAST(ImplementationCompiler.java:498)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.ImplementationCompiler.parse1(ImplementationCompiler.java:196)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.mxml.MxmlCompiler.parse1(MxmlCompiler.java:168)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.parse1(CompilerAPI.java:2851)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.parse1(CompilerAPI.java:2804)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.batch2(CompilerAPI.java:446)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.batch(CompilerAPI.java:1274)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.compile(CompilerAPI.java:1488)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.CompilerAPI.compile(CompilerAPI.java:1375)
    [mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.Mxmlc.mxmlc(Mxmlc.java:282)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    [mxmlc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    [mxmlc]     at flex.ant.FlexTask.executeInProcess(FlexTask.java:280)
    [mxmlc]     at flex.ant.FlexTask.execute(FlexTask.java:225)
    [mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    [mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    [mxmlc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

BUILD FAILED
/src/build.xml:49: mxmlc task failed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the Java-VM more heap-space, e.g.

```
java -Xmx1024M
```

or whatever you need :-). Under Linux (and probably other Unixes), that could do the trick with the ant binary:

```
ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024M" ant
```

Comment: Thanks. looks like that worked but only when I bumped it up to 4GB!

Answer (score 5):

We were using ant to build a flex app on an individual machine (without flex builder) and the only way that solved the heap space error was to increase the maxmemory in build.xml.

Setting ant_opts and java config did not work for us.

```
<mxmlc file="${src-cp}/CP_main.mxml" output="${bin-dir}/CP/CP_main.swf" 
    show-unused-type-selector-warnings="false"
    static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="true" fork="true" maxmemory="1024m">
```

More info http://tipila.com/tips/java-heap-error-when-building-flex-application-with-ant

Comment: Why **show-unused-type-selector-warnings** is `false`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues with compc. The only thing that seemed to help me was to set fork="true" maxmemory="256m"

Comment: Where did you determine the number **256m** from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching an Ant task from within Flash Builder, go to `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Edit` and add the appropriate command line argument for Java under *Default VM Arguments*, e.g. `-Xmx4096M`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was compiling several different SWFs when I added the 5th one that is when I got the memory error. The way I solved it was with a little bit of a hack. I spawned new JVMs for each swf I was compiling by using the exec ant task.

```
<target name="main">
            <exec executable="ant" os="Mac OS X">
                <arg value="antTargetCompileSwf1"/>
            </exec>
            <exec executable="ant" os="Windows 2000,Windows NT,Windows XP,Windows 8">
                <arg value="antTargetCompileSwf1"/>
            </exec>
            <exec executable="ant" os="Mac OS X">
                <arg value="antTargetCompileSwf2"/>
            </exec>
            <exec executable="ant" os="Windows 2000,Windows NT,Windows XP,Windows 8">
                <arg value="antTargetCompileSwf2"/>
            </exec>
        </target>
```

This is an example where I reference each target antTargetCompileSwf2 in the same build file which would contain the mxmlc task that was originally throwing the memory error